# Работа с датами ldap в БД firebird

Tags: sql, дата, firebird, datetime, ldap

Подскажите, может кто сталкивался уже. 
Требуется PSQL Stored Functions для того чтобы писать/читать (в человекопонятном виде) из БД firebird даты и время, которые хранятся в формате ldap.

DDL таблицы

```
CREATE TABLE DESK_INCIDENTS (
  ID BIGINT NOT NULL,
  AUTHOR_ID BIGINT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
  COMMENT_ID BIGINT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
  DATE_CREATE BIGINT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Какое несчастье в жизни Вас заставило писать в базу дату в формате LDAP я не знаю. Но, несчастье, видимо, большое, потому, что Вы ее пишете даже не строкой, а числом. Хотя как вы умудрились преобразовать запись `20030806100459.0Z`в число - это отдельный вопрос.

Сам "формат LDAP" это строка в формате `yyyymmddhhnnss.T`, где `Т` - часовой пояс.

Ну вот Вам процедура, которая превращает Ваше число в TIMESTAMP, путем последовательного выделения разрядов

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_NUM_TO_TIMESTAMP (
  in_num BIGINT)
RETURNS (
  out_date TIMESTAMP)
AS
  DECLARE VARIABLE var_str CHAR(19);
BEGIN
  var_str = :in_num;
  var_str =
    SUBSTRING(:var_str FROM 1 FOR 4) || '-' ||
    SUBSTRING(:var_str FROM 5 FOR 2) || '-' ||
    SUBSTRING(:var_str FROM 7 FOR 2) || ' ' ||
    SUBSTRING(:var_str FROM 9 FOR 2) || ':' ||
    SUBSTRING(:var_str FROM 11 FOR 2) || ':' ||
    SUBSTRING(:var_str FROM 13 FOR 2);
  out_date = :var_str;
END
```

И обратное преобразование

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_TIMESTAMP_TO_NUM (
  in_date TIMESTAMP)
RETURNS (
  out_num BIGINT)
AS
  DECLARE VARIABLE var_str VARCHAR(32);
BEGIN
  var_str = :in_date;
  var_str =
    SUBSTRING(:var_str FROM 1 FOR 4) ||
    SUBSTRING(:var_str FROM 6 FOR 2) ||
    SUBSTRING(:var_str FROM 9 FOR 2) ||
    SUBSTRING(:var_str FROM 12 FOR 2) ||
    SUBSTRING(:var_str FROM 15 FOR 2) ||
    SUBSTRING(:var_str FROM 18 FOR 2);
  out_num = :var_str;
END
```

Но еще раз - пересмотрите свое отношение к хранению данных и храните изначально в TIMESTAMP. Вы этим **сильно** облегчите себе жизнь

Comment: Спасибо! Таким форматом пользуется софтина teamwox. А мне необходимо выгружать из нее данные. Поэтому буду стараться преобразовывать дату к '2017-01-31 00:00:00' сразу в запросе, что бы было удобно делать выгрузку.

Comment: @AnastasiyaKochmar Если мой ответ решил Вашу проблему, отметьте его как правильный